# Cancelling apartment booking in Switzerland

Tags: bookings, switzerland

I have made a booking with an apartment in Switzerland. No booking payment was done and I did not share my credit card details with them. But I did fill in the confirmation letter which have my details (passport, address) and signed.

According to them, if I would like to cancel the booking I have to pay 80% of the total sum. But since they do not have my credit card details, can I just ignore them? And with this can they give any trouble?

Answer (score 7):

According to swiss law, you have no right to cancel your booking. So if you cancel your booking you actually have to pay 80 %.

> According to [a lawyer in Switzerland](https://www.geissmannlegal.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/Dokumente/PDF/Publikationen/Aktuelle_Rechtsfragen/Ko_Beitrag_vom_02.05.2011.pdf):
> Grundsätzlich besteht kein Recht, vom
> Vertrag zurückzutreten. Wichtige persönliche Gründe, die einem Mieter die Ferien
> verunmöglichen (Todesfall eines nahen Angehörigen, Unfall, Krankheit,
> Scheidung, etc.) räumen diesem keinen kostenlosen Rücktritt vom Mietvertrag
> ein. Gebräuchlich sind jedoch Vertragsklauseln, wonach dem Mieter beim vorzeitigen
> Rücktritt, je nach Ankündigungsfrist, ein Teil der Mietzinszahlung erlassen
> wird.

Normally if you cancel early enough, you may be able to talk to the owner and explain the situation. If you just ignore him, he will be able to pursue you through government help (Betreibungsbegehren) or through a debt collection agency. Also IMHO it's really nice of that Appartements owner of not collecting your Credit Card information and he will probably start doing that to other people, if you don't pay.

Comment: Thank you Daan. Yes, the management is really nice. We have made a deal which if they managed to find a subs tenant, I do not have to pay for the cancellation.

Comment: Hi Daan, I forgot to mention that I will be in Swiss as a tourist. So is 'Betreibungsbegehren' and debt collection agency still applicable?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but i think, the "Betreibungsbegehren is not really international, altoug it could potentially lead to be stopped at the boarder in future visits to pay the fee. Debt can be collected internationally through debt collection agencys.